# Oracle 10g sql query

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have some data like this ↓

```
T_ID    T_PERIOD    T_COUNT    T_SUM        T_UPDATE_COUNT
1       2013-2014   3436       20118043         0
2       2014-2015   4298       27101356         0
3       2015-2016   5577       38844640         0
4       2016-2017   5764       40701339         0
5       2017-2018   6997       54316874         0
6       2018-2019   13315      151012820        0
7       2019-2020   13933      162731044        0
8       2018-2019   13300      150000000        1
9       2013-2014   3600       21000000         1
10      2018-2019   13500      155000000        2
```

This table only has insert,during insert T_UPDATE_COUNT = max(T_UPDATE_COUNT) + 1 ;

I want the data to look like this ↓

```
T_ID    T_PERIOD    T_COUNT    T_SUM        T_UPDATE_COUNT
9       2013-2014   3600       21000000         1
2       2014-2015   4298       27101356         0
3       2015-2016   5577       38844640         0
4       2016-2017   5764       40701339         0
5       2017-2018   6997       54316874         0
10      2018-2019   13500      155000000        2
7       2019-2020   13933      162731044        0
```

How do i write SQL statement ?

Comment: Can you explain what is the logic behind the expected result?

Comment: These data are obtained from another table "group by". They are all historical data and basically will not change, but they do change. I don't want to do the "delete, update" operation.

So what I thought at that time was that if the period data changed, I would write the latest period data into the table, field't '_ UPDATE_ Count '+ 1 is used to distinguish.

Comment: Thank you for the solution, because the amount of data is very small, I think maybe I can add an is_ Delete field, when data changes' update is'_ In this way, the query statement will be simpler.

Comment: The English is generated by translation software, I hope it's right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you need to get all the rows with the maximum value of `T_UPDATE_COUNT` for each `T_PERIOD` , you may try:

```
select T_ID, T_PERIOD, T_COUNT, T_SUM, T_UPDATE_COUNT
from 
(
    select T_ID, T_PERIOD, T_COUNT, T_SUM, T_UPDATE_COUNT,
           row_number() over (partition by T_PERIOD order by T_UPDATE_COUNT desc) as RN
    from yourData x
)
where RN = 1
```

There are different ways to do this; I believe this one is clear enough: the inner query is used to compute the row number in the set of all the rows with the same value of `T_PERIOD` (`partition by T_PERIOD`) and name it `RN`.
The external one simply filters this result to only get the first rows (`RN = 1`) of each group.

Comment: Thank you  ，That's what I want to do。